# How to create RUN command for windows Application

Tags: windows, window

Like we have "winword" to open MS Word doc, notepad to open notepad and many other(like control,chrome to open chrome browser, similarly firefox).
Can we create a custom RUN commmand for a given application/Software, kind of short name, which I can directly use in the RUN command, to open that given application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shall put your program.exe folder in the environment path, and type "program" to launch it from the cmd shell and remember to put double quotes around paths having blank spaces in it

Comment: Thanks for you response. For example, i need to run sublime Text, its path is D:\sublimeText3\Sublime Text Build 3083 x64\sublime_text.exe, I tried putting it in the PATH variable, but didn't work...what am i doing wrong

Comment: @hemal, Explorer/start->run sees the environment variables which it received when it started. You probably need to log out and log back in again to get the new path.

Comment: @Hemal Don't put the executable name into the path

Comment: Yes, I simply had to log off and login again, Strange I thought it did pick up the changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `exe` application path into *Windows* environment path.

Comment: Thanks for you response. For example, i need to run sublime Text, its path is D:\sublimeText3\Sublime Text Build 3083 x64\sublime_text.exe, I tried putting it in the PATH variable, but didn't work...what am i doing wrong